# What are C++ arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, c++, arrays

Found the solution. All I have to do is wrap the email addresses with quotes.

(I need to go through a mailing list and send the mail when the program hits a comma. This is a bit confusing- it works in C++!)

Comment: I've no idea what you're talking about. Arrays are not arrays? They sure look like and act like arrays.

Comment: One of the best things about PHP is the extensive documentation. Check out http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php It should solve your question.

Comment: They are not the version of arrays that C++ uses.

Comment: user3653438- that does not answer my question. What are C++ arrays in PHP?

Comment: @KeithTyler: As I understand it, the OP would like some construction in PHP that uses a dense, contiguous in-memory representation of the array elements (as opposed to, say, a hash table).

Comment: You can do the same thing with PHP "arrays" which is more a hash table. What do you intend to achieve?

Comment: I think what you are referring to in PHP _are_ strings rather than arrays. Arrays mean something a bit different in PHP. If your mailing list is a string, you should be able to divide it up into separate addresses (substrings) using explode. It is a bit difficult to be sure exactly what you mean, though. Can you include a bit of code and explain what you're trying to do with it?

Comment: What do you mean, *exactly*, by "C++ arrays in PHP"?

Comment: Don't Panic- explode is the one I need- thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use `explode(",",$list_of_emails)` and then loop over the resulting array of email addresses to do your sending.

You could also probably do this in `bash` with `cut` and/or `xargs`.

Answer (score 1):

An array, both in PHP in C++ are a list of elements with inside date, in array you can put string, number and other.
From `cplusplus.com`, array is:

> An array is a series of elements of the same type placed in contiguous memory locations that can be individually referenced by adding an index to a unique identifier.

`php.net` say:

```
An array in PHP is actually an ordered map. A map is a type that associates values to keys. This type is optimized for several different uses; it can be treated as an array, list (vector), hash table (an implementation of a map), dictionary, collection, stack, queue, and probably more. As array values can be other arrays, trees and multidimensional arrays are also possible.
```

Like you can see the concept is equal both in PHP that in C++.

In C++ an array can be created like a variable but with {}, an example of array in C++ is here:

```
int array [] = { 16, 2, 77, 40, 12071 };

  cout << array[0]
```

This code  create an array with 5 elements, and print the first element, an array start from [0] and not from [1](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/).

WIth PHP an array can be created with there code:

```
    <?php
$array = array(
    1    => "a",
    "1"  => "b",
    1.5  => "c",
    true => "d",
);
var_dump($array);
?>
```

This code print it:

> array(1) { [1](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/)=> string(1) "d" }

Is it better use array or create much variables? Array is a better way in programming and often is recommended.

I link you the official documentation on array (both PHP and C++). 

[Array C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/)

[Array PHP](http://php.net/manual/it/language.types.array.php)

Comment: `$array[0]` will be undefined since this key has not been set.

Comment: Now I fix it, wait

Comment: I have fix it, thanks